Invalid argument error when using `smbc_open`
*I downloaded and installed Samba-4.15.5 on Ubuntu, and when I use smbc_open in my program, it always shows an "invalid argument" error. However, I am sure that the address I entered is correct because I was able to transfer files correctly using smbclient.

The command I used for the transfer is as follows:*
$ smbclient -L \\R067-2204017/SMB -U group/dima%0000 -c 'put /home/dima/Log/test.txt test' 

*Another issue is that when I use the smbc_set_credentials() function from libsmbclient.h and compile, I always get an error stating that smbc_set_credentials() is not defined. Other functions in libsmbclient.h work correctly, but the definition of smbc_set_credentials() cannot be found, which is confusing to me.
How should I resolve or analyze this issue?
Thank you.
Best Regards,
Dima Lee
I hope to correctly use the functions in libsmbclient.h for file transfer between Linux and Windows.*

Perhaps use forward slashes or quote the host.
